# RoR InvalidAuthenticityToken with Active Storage direct upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am trying to use rails active storage to directly upload to an Amazon s3 bucket. However, let's treat this as directly uploading when the storage medium is the local disk, because I can't get that to work either.

I am unable to do this without `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):`
 errors.

I have followed this guide exactly: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads

I have even gone so far as to disable csrf application wide with this line of code in my `application_controller.rb` `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`

This only happens when I have `direct_upload: true` in my form.

Here is my form:

`<%= form_with url: messages_path do |form| %>
      <%= form.label 'Upload' %>
      <%= form.file_field :audio_message, class: 'form-control', direct_upload: true, :required => true%>
      <%= form.submit 'Upload file', class: 'form-control' %>
<% end %>`

Comment: @hashrocket This is proper syntax. If it weren't I'd be getting a different error no?

Comment: Do you have `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in your application layout.

Comment: @hashrocket Yes, I should have stated, it's one of the many things I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ajax submit did not pick up the token. You can try either one of these:

1. Tell the form to embed token `<%= form_with url: messages_path, authenticity_token: true...%>`
2. add `config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true` in config

See if they help you. My guess is purely from this: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with